# Wildcard for last 2 segments of a IPv4 address in nginx

Tags: nginx, ipv4

In nginx we can define access (allow/deny) rules [as follows](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule):

```
allow   192.168.1.0/24;
allow   10.1.1.0/1
```

However when we want to use wildcard for last 2 segments of an IP address,

```
allow 192.168.0/255.0/255
```

that does not work and it says this syntax is incorrect. What is the way to do that? Is it impossible because two segments mean different subnets or what? An explanation about this would be a great resource for future, I assume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
allow 192.168.0.0/16;
```

Your 10.1.1 rule is wrong, what are you trying to accomplish with it?

The syntax is [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) network numbering.

Comment: Wrong rule is in nginx documentation as you can see.